# Emojis are not working between Android App and server

Tags: android, web-services, rest, emoji

I am sending emojis to server and display them in the newsfeed. but emojis are shown like garbage text. What's wrong i am doing. 
Here is my code to send data to server.

```
if(method.equals("POST")) 
        {
            Log.i("URL_POST", url);
            // request method is POST
            httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Set Character
            entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8");

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if(entity != null) {
                inputstream = entity.getContent();

                String resultstring = convertStreamToString(inputstream);

                inputstream.close();

                return resultstring;
            }

        } else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            Log.i("URL_GET", url);
            httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if(entity != null) {
                inputstream = entity.getContent();

                String resultstring = convertStreamToString(inputstream);

                inputstream.close();

                return resultstring;
            }
        }
```

Here i parse the response from the server.

```
 if (pagesObj.has("feed_status")) {
                     objFeed.setStatus(Html.fromHtml(pagesObj.getString("feed_status")).toString());
                }
```

After parsing and display data to listview, emojis are not showing properly i am using https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon library for showing emojis in android app.

Kindly help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "shown like garbage"? Example would be helpful. (e.g. Raw HTML Output shown)

Comment: Shown like that ߘİߘ0ߘ԰ߘ̰ߐѰߐװߐڰߐ